# Monotonic increasing subsequence that converges to $sup{\{X_m}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let ${\{X_m}\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded above and $A=sup{\{X_m}\}$.

I was first required to find a convergent sequence that's limit is not $A$, and I think I've done so with the sequence ${\{1,1/2,1/3,...}\}$ which has a supremum of $1$ but converges to $0$.

Next, I'm required to prove that if none of the terms of ${\{X_m}\}$ is equal to $A$, then ${\{X_m}\}$ must have a monotonic increasing subsequence that converges to $A$, and I'm entirely unsure of where to begin for this proof. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the definition of the supremum. That $A$ is the supremum of the $X_m$ means that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$0<A-X_k<\varepsilon$$
The LHS inequality is because none of the $X_m$ is equal to $A$. 
First you can find a term $X_{k(1)}$ of the sequence such that
$$0<A-X_{k(1)}<1$$
Then you can find a term $X_{k_2}$ such that
$$0<A-X_{k_2}<\min\left(A-X_{k_1}\,,\,\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$
using the definition of $A$ as a supremum so that $X_{k_2}>X_{k_1}$. Try to follow this idea and build a subsequence $X_{k_m}$ by induction which converges increasingly to $A$.